# SLURM squeue format argument fails from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, jobs, slurm

I'm trying to call the [SLURM squeue](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) from a python script.  The command,

`/usr/bin/squeue --Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft`

Works fine from the command line, but fails from [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/n/home00/DilithiumMatrix/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/n/home00/DilithiumMatrix/.conda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/squeue --Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft'
```

MWE:

```
import subprocess
command = "/usr/bin/squeue --Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft"
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
text = p.stdout.read()
print(text)
```

`/usr/bin/squeue` works fine from both the command line or `Popen`.

Could it be failing because it requires some information about the user/group that's executing the  `squeue` command and that is (somehow) lost when running via python?  What else could be causing this?

Comment: What does your call to `subprocess.Popen` look like? How does it fail?

Comment: @MarkkuK. woops, sorry --- MWE and error message included.

Comment: You need to pass your command as a list of strings: `command = ["/usr/bin/squeue", "--Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft"]`

Comment: Damn.  I tried both `"/usr/bin/squeue --Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft"` and `["/usr/bin/squeue", "--Format=", "username,jobid,name,timeleft"]`, but not the compromise case... do you know why it doesn't work otherwise?  I'd be happy to accept your answer if you submitted one!  Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks, I submitted an answer. Your second form would be like calling `/usr/bin/squeue` on the command line with a space after the `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `subprocess.Popen` is either a String, or a list of Strings. If it is a single String, it will be interpreted as a filename. This is the reason for the error you get.
To pass a list of Strings, it should match how a shell would pass your arguments to the process. A standard shell will split your command line by whitespace, so instead of this:

```
command = "/usr/bin/squeue --Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft"
```

You need this:

```
command = ["/usr/bin/squeue", "--Format=username,jobid,name,timeleft"]
```

Splitting the second argument at the "=" as you mentioned in your comment just confuses squeue, which would then see two arguments.